# Automatic certbot certificate - how to skip question?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I have to renew Let's Encrypt certificates on my Debian server. By some reason the renew option doesn't works, and nor the certbot-auto script.

This below command works, but asking some questions:

```
sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d *.blogginger.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly
```

Questions while I'm running this command:

1. Would you like to redirect HTTP to HTTPS? I choose here option 1
2. Are you OK with your IP being logged?

   and press Enter at the end.

How can I skip these questions? Which parameters should I use with certbot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was this below command to renew all certificate on the server, included the mentioned certificate as well:

```
sudo certbot renew
```

I insert this command in crontab for never forget to renew any certificates:

```
0 4 * * 0 sudo certbot renew
```

It will send a request at every early morning of Sunday.

Hide standard output and show only errors by addig "-q" parameter:

```
sudo certbot renew -q
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like letsencrypt have forgotten the options used when generating the certs originally.

If you manually run just certbot, with only the least possible options, and when asked, select the "don't alter apache config" option, I think the options will be saved for next run of `certbot-auto renew`